# Google Calendar API - Status Tentative

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar V3 API and I notice some calendar events are coming from the API with a status of Tentative.  Can anyone tell me how this status comes about and how I can replicate it?

This is causing issues as my app is only syncing with calendar events which have a status of confirmed.

I've tried replicating using the online version of Google Calendar and app on Android but there doesn't seem to be a way to set tentative.

I've tried adding myself and others as guests and then setting attending to "maybe" - this isn't the answer and still comes through as "confirmed".

Comment: When invitee accepts event as "may be", then this comes as tentative. When you try like this are you not seeing it as tentative or while synching tentative events comes as confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

I did find a flow where the event status turned out to be "tentative". I created an event in Outlook calendar and set the status of the calendar as "tentative" (this can be done in outlook calendar UI). Now, I shared that event to my google calendar by adding my google calendar ID as participant. Since the ics file has the status to be "tentative", the event status was set as "tentative"  when fetched with Google Calendar API. However, I did not find a way to directly create a tentative event in Google Calendar UI itself.